# Extracting word patterns between quotes

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've summarised my XML document to an array, and I would appreciate some help with `reg_exp` magic.

This is an example of my array:

```
[64] => "200004008993","PART":"1003261894","VKN":"28445521001","INK":"00000000000101926661","BP":"0000000101","DAT":"20190823","ENDAT":"20190826","UPTDAT":"00000000","CLOSE":"X","UPDATED":"00000000","COLL":"200040089939-078-9","NAME_":"ARIVAVL.FILIPDEDIOL","CITY1":"Dubrovnik","POST_CODE1":"20000","STREET":"CVIJETEZUZORI\u01061","HOUSE_NUM":null,"MAIL_CITY1":"SomeCity","MAIL_POST":"20000","MAIL_STREET":"SomeStreetName","MAIL_HOUSE":null,"ITEM":[{"SEGMENT":"1","BEL":"019234104313","XB":"2844552100119061","FAED":"20190617","AGD":"20190823","INITAMNT":"61.51","PAYAMNT":"61.51","WRTOFFAMNT":"0.00","OPENAMNT":"0.00","INVAMNT":"61.51","WS":"AUD","REC":"00000000"},{"SEGMENT":"1","OPB":"019234171002","XBL":"2844552100119071","FAE":"20190717","AG":"20190823","INITAMNT":"61.25","PAYAMNT":"61.25","WRTOFFAMNT":"0.00","OPENAMNT":"0.00","INVAMNT":"61.25","WS":"HRK","REC":"00000000"}],"MSISDN":{"MSI":"3858909851217"},"MCD":{"MCD_M":null,"MCD_AT":null},"PHONE":null},{"SEGMENT":"1","
```

Thing is, I only need number contained between first quotes, all occurrences of: `INITAMNT, PAYAMNT, WRTOFFAMNT, OPENAMNT, INVAMNT` including corresponding amount displayed in numbers, like:

```
[64] => "200004008993","INITAMNT":"61.51","PAYAMNT":"61.51","WRTOFFAMNT":"0.00","OPENAMNT":"0.00","INVAMNT":"61.51","INITAMNT":"61.25","PAYAMNT":"61.25","WRTOFFAMNT":"0.00","OPENAMNT":"0.00","INVAMNT":"61.25"
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't process the XML directly.  You seem to be doing so much processing to get the data you want it might be better to learn how to process XML first.

Comment: Ive tried process it on a DOM level, but i couldnt get rid of that hideous SampleXML and @attribute objects

Comment: Perhaps if you post a question asking how to do it, you may get some insight into the problems and how it can be solved.  Only a suggestion - it's up to you.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant way to do it, just to explain the whole situation from the beginning requires others to do the whole work all over again, this way i know what i did, and how to make some changes in the future if required